# Loading a JS file with web asset manager for Bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, modal, joomla-5.x, web-asset-manager

I'm loading a Bootstrap modal file in HtmlView.php and then a js file to manage it with the following schema:

**joomla.asset.json**

```
...
"assets": [
    {
        "name": "almacen.modal_pintura",
        "type": "script",
        "uri": "com_almacen/modal_pintura.js",
        "dependencies": [
            "jquery",
            "core"
        ],
        "attributes": {
            "defer": true
        }
    }
  ]
...
```

**HtmlView.php**

```
...
    public function display($tpl = null)
    {
        ....
        include_once ('components/com_almacen/modal/modal_pintura.php');
        
        $wa = $this->document->getWebAssetManager();
        $wa->useScript('almacen.modal_pintura');
        ....
```

**modal_pintura.php**

```
...
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_pintura"  tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    ....
</div>
```

**modal_pintura.js**

```
$('#modal_pintura').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    console.log('Event: ', event);
});
```

js function is loaded and modal open on click a button, but show.bs.modal event doesn't fire. It only works wrapping all js code in a jQuery .ready function:

**modified modal_pintura.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#modal_pintura').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        console.log('Event: ', event);
    });
});
```

Please, Is there any different dependencies or attributes to include in joomla.asset.json for load js file after all html or specific php file?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Wrapping in `jQuery.ready()` shouldn't be necessary since you're already using `defer` attribute.

Comment: Thanks again,Sharky, you are always there to help us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing and testing, in joomla.asset.json file I have removed jQuery dependency,
reordering and I don't know why but finally it works!

**joomla.asset.json**

```
...
    {
        "name": "almacen.arandela",
        "type": "script",
        "uri": "com_almacen/arandela.js",
        "attributes": {
            "defer": true
        },
        "dependencies": [
            "core"
        ]
    }
...
```